# Weighted Rank Data Analysis

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, chi-squared

I have a data set that looks like the following:

```
           x1    x2    x3    x4   Weight 
Factor1    1     3     10     1     4 
Factor2    3     4      2     9     1
Factor3    3     5      6     1     3
Factor4    4     3      1     5     3
Factor5    5     8      4     8     2
```

Where x represents people and factor represents the treatment variable. The values in the first 4 columns represent risk on a scale from 1 through 10 and the weight column represents the weighted importance (1-5) of that value. I would like to create a meaningful analysis to see which x has the greatest risk based on the various factors and their weights but am unsure of how I should approach this. Since I know this is ranked data, I thought that a Friedman Test would make sense. I would also like to analyze this in R.

Comment: Why not multiply the observations by their weights and then run tests on the means of the variables?

Comment: I agree about multiplying the observations by their weights. Is there a reason why a test of means might be better than a Friedman Test? I'm 'weighing' which test is the best for this type of data :)

Comment: I don’t think there is a reason. The Friedman test is a great idea :) Perhaps you could run it and add it to your question